# SSO + JWT Validation Best Practice?

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, jwt, single-sign-on

so i want to ask question about JWT Validation.

My springboot project implementing jwt validation for any api request except login and logout endpoint.
my login and logout endpoint (..../api/v1/auth/login, ..../api/v1/auth/logout) is SSO based from another source.
So when i login with that SSO, they are returning their JWT token to my backend process.

then, when i hit my another api, i want to validate it first with the generated jwt before, but although my jwt was match, it always give 401 error.

then this is my authentication class :

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher;


import io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.MalformedJwtException;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureException;
import io.jsonwebtoken.UnsupportedJwtException;


public class AuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    @Value("${xxxx.app.client_secret}")
    private String clientSecret;
    
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthenticationFilter.class);
    
    AuthenticationFilter(final RequestMatcher requiresAuth) {
        super(requiresAuth);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {

        String tokenRequest = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");
        validateJwtToken(tokenRequest.substring(7));
        Authentication requestAuthentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(tokenRequest, tokenRequest);
        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(requestAuthentication);


    }

    
    public boolean validateJwtToken(String authToken) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(clientSecret).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
            return true;
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT signature: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT token: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            logger.error("JWT token is expired: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("JWT token is unsupported: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.error("JWT claims string is empty: {}", e.getMessage());
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

in **validateJwtToken** method, there is no problem since it give me **true** return, but when it back to  attemptAuthentication, it catch error like this in that class

```
catch (InternalAuthenticationServiceException failed) {
            logger.error(
                    "An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.",
                    failed);
            unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, failed);

            return;
```

sorry for my bad code, this is my first time implementing a jwt security to my project. So what should i do when i have case like this ? thank you, any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this: If the token is generated by username as Subject, then parse it from token and pass to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken to verify in database and set in SecurityContext

```
String username = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(clientSecret).parseClaimsJws(authToken).getBody().getSubject();
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, new ArrayList<>()); 
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

Spring Security UserDetailsService custom implementation ex:

```
public class UserDeatilsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
   // ApplicationUser - example for entity representing user in application
    ApplicationUser user = // here call your SSO service returing username
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
    }
    return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), emptyList());
}}
```

Configuration in Application SecurityConfiguration class:

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Autowired
private UserDeatilsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceImpl);
}
// other configurations ...
```

Comment: unfortunatelly the username coming from sso source and i'm not store it into my database

Comment: can you try to create custom UserDetailsService implementation and configure it in your SpringSecurityConfiguration class, i have given example in answer